# Syntax error in my trigger in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I need to create triggers for an exercice, i have 3 tables, which one have one int argument and i want to create this trigger:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER D1_1 BEFORE INSERT ON T1 FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) < 1)
   INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(6) 
   END;
```

Syntaxe error near THEN..

Thank you!

Comment: This is not how a trigger is created in Postgres. Please see the examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need conditional logic:

```
    INSERT INTO T2
        SELECT 6
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2);
```

Note that `NOT EXISTS` is generally more efficient than `COUNT(*) = 0`.  `NOT EXISTS` stops at the first matching row, rather going through the entire table to count everything -- and then doing something if there are no rows.

Comment: No, i really need this trigger, cuz i have 5 others triggers and they are linked, i need this trigger ^^

Comment: @valt . . . You can incorporate this logic into a trigger.  I left out the trigger definition, because it would seem to distract from the logic of the query.